# can we get the time between two inputs?

Tags: c++, input, time, cin

I was wondering while watching this code :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int a,b;

    cout << "enter 1";
    cin  >> a;

    cout << "enter 2";
     cin >> b;

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

if we can get the time gap between the input of variables a and b successively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `time()` to get current time and `difftime()` to compute the difference.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a,b;
    cout<<"enter 1";
    cin>>a;
    time_t atime = time(NULL);
    cout<<"enter 2";
    cin>>b;
    time_t btime = time(NULL);
    cout << difftime(btime, atime) << " seconds passed\n";
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @OrelEraki I don't agree. OP asked for _the time gap between the input of variables a and b_. If `atime` is fetched one line earlier, than the time waiting for `a` is counted in.

Comment: @timaru from where can I get detailed info about library     ctime and time_t

Comment: Search fot it on Google.

Answer (score 2):

time(), difftime() has a resolution of one second.

The recommended method would be to use the [chrono library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) (c++11)

```
#include <chrono>

// ...

// take time 0
auto Time0= chrono::system_clock::now();

// do some work ...

// take time 1
auto Time1= chrono::system_clock::now();

// print the diff (in this example: in milliseconds)
auto Duration= chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(Time1 - Time0).count();
cout << Duration << endl;
```